# Overtype issue in git bash using mongo

Tags: mongodb, shell, git-bash

I'm trying to use git bash for mongo. It works well but there are some issues that are annoying for working :

- the cursor can go anywhere in the shell, so it's easy to start typing in the wrong place

ex : "db.compositors.find()" [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSw41.png)

- I can't type "up arrow" to get the previous command, instead it moves the cursor :/

Does anyone have a trick to fix this ?

Thanks !

(I got other issues in the default windows shell or in the mongo shell like difficulties to copy/paste, so I'd prefer use git bash)

Answer (score 1):

You can use settings from the bin file system for git bash to specify that up arrow is for history-search-backwords and down arrow for history-search-forward. However try using cmder as a terminal for Windows which works best and has many cool features as well : http://cmder.net/

Comment: Hello !

I' didn't find are the settings from the bin file system for git bash but I don't think it could work because usually, git bash recognize up and down arrows for cmd history. It's only when I use 'mongo' that it didn't works (I also have another issue : it's in overwrite mode and I can't insert text :/ )

But I tried cmder and it works well !

Thanks !